# Does PHP code execute when included

Tags: php, javascript, include

On my website I use `include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/header.php");` to include my header. But in my `header.php` I have a script tag inside the head tag. My question was, does this script gets executed when I include it into my pages.

This is my part of my header.php:
http://pastebin.com/FbFG3B7E

Comment: yes, they get executed after you include them, it's like you put their code in your main file.

Comment: Well, yes. What kind of script tag though? If it's javascript then no it's executed client side. Include basically acts as if you "included" the other file's code right there.

Comment: Yes and no. The contents in the script tag won't be executed by PHP when included because PHP doesn't execute JS code. But they should be executed when they're loaded by the browser. It's important to note there's a distinction between server side code and client side code.

Comment: It is a small code for my Live support. It's from Zopim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The include statement includes and evaluates the specified file.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

That means, PHP gets evaluated and executed. If you mean a HTML script-tag: It just will be printed out. Your browser will retrieve also the HTML in the included file and handle it (also executing the script).

EDIT:
I get following error at your page:

> SyntaxError: missing name after . operator
>
> window.||(function(d,s){var z==function(c){z._.push(c)},$=z.s=

At that position you want to print a variable `$zopim`. Try it with `{$zopim}`.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
   window.||(function(d,s){var z==function(c){z._.push(c)},$=z.s=
   d.createElement(s),e=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];z.set=function(o){z.set.
   _.push(o)};z._=[];z.set._=[];$.async=!0;$.setAttribute('charset','utf-8');
   $.src='//cdn.zopim.com/?xxxx';z.t=+new Date;$.
   type='text/javascript';e.parentNode.insertBefore($,e)})(document,'script');
  </script>

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't work or execute.

Comment: Then you should edit your post and add the part of the `header.php`. Have you checked the HTML source code the browser receives if the included <script> is in it? Have you tested the included <script> on its own by putting it into a html file and open it in your browser?

Comment: I included it. It is a paste bin link. Figuered that would be better then on this post.

Comment: And my website link is voxelhost.com but it doesn't show the live chat on the right bottom corner.

Comment: So what do I have to do to fix it?

Comment: edited. also check if `$zopim` exists and whats in it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using `include();` and `require();` behaves as if you're just copying the code straight into your page.

Comment: But why doesn't it work like the other pages then?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a JavaScript script tag, then yes, it will be executed when the browser loads the page.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
   window.||(function(d,s){var z==function(c){z._.push(c)},$=z.s=
   d.createElement(s),e=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];z.set=function(o){z.set.
   _.push(o)};z._=[];z.set._=[];$.async=!0;$.setAttribute('charset','utf-8');
   $.src='//cdn.zopim.com/?xxxx';z.t=+new Date;$.
   type='text/javascript';e.parentNode.insertBefore($,e)})(document,'script');
  </script>